# addClass actually removes the class in my code

Tags: jquery

`addClass("x")` actually removes the *class* **"x"** in my code.  When checking with *debugger*, `removeClass("x")` is getting called nowhere.

Here is my code,

```
$('.list-item > li:first-child').addClass('hide-lead');
```

Anyone help!

Comment: Please show the working code to help in better understanding.

Comment: yeah more code is defo needed!

Comment: someone gave you a jquery library that switched the addClass functionality with the removeClass:)))

Comment: @madalinivascu your funny

Comment: @Seabizkit can happen :))

Comment: @Subbu you are looking for `removeClass` what about `removeAttr()`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't have any extra `jquery` script in your code?

there is a sample of your code and it works: 
https://jsfiddle.net/sebas07b/0bLLjojh/2/

I can't see anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<style>
    .hide-lead {
    color:red;
    }

</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#add').click(function () {
            $('.list-item > li:first-child').addClass('hide-lead');
        });

        $('#remove').click(function () {
            $('.list-item > li:first-child').removeClass('hide-lead');
        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Add Class" id="add" />
        <input type="button" value="Remove Class" id="remove" />
  <ul class="list-item">
      <li>hello1</li>
        <li>hello2</li> 
       <li>hello3</li>


  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you guys said, I have called removeClass by mistake in my code. After a long struggle found out the removeClass hiding inside my long jquery.